# Finding the root of the matrix representation of a cyclic permutation of lenght $n$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am wondering if there is a general formula for the matrix square root of the representation $C_n$ of a cyclic permutation  of period $n$. The matrix $A$ such that $A^2=C_n$.
For example $n=3$:
$$
A^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 &0&1\\
1&0&0\\
0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}=C_3
$$

Comment: There are general results for the square root of such "circulant" matrices, see [here](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2013/601243/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $A^2=C_3$ has two obvious solutions with left-upper corner equal to zero, which are even integral, namely
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & -1 \cr -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\; A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & 1 \cr 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. 
$$
In general, there are several articles on squares roots of [circulant matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).